# Virtualenv for django in VS Code not working, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code

I've been following a tutorial on how to start using django and creating a virtual env on VS Code, but it doesn't work.. For what it shows in the tutorial, it's supposed to create a folder called ".vscode" with a json file inside called "settings.json" that contains the python path to the python interpreter..
But in my case, none of those files appear.. I THINK there might be sth wrong with the path where it creates the virtual env, but since I'm pretty new at this, I can hardly say..
This are the steps I followed:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON>cd DJANGO

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO>mkdir storefront

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO>cd storefront

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO\storefront>pipenv install django

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO\storefront>code .

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO\storefront>pipenv shell

(storefront-vT5YbUlq) C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO\storefront>django-admin startproject storefront .

(storefront-vT5YbUlq) C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Andres\Programación\5. Prácticas\3. PYTHON\DJANGO\storefront>pipenv --venv
```

** So the command prompt returns me this:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\.virtualenvs\storefront-vT5YbUlq
```

I'm supposed to copy that line to "Enter interpreter path" in VSCode, and after that it should create those vscode folder and json file.. but that doesn't happen, so I can't use the VS terminal to run the server

I'm going insane with this, I just can't understand where's the problem

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with that

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- using terminal, `mkdir` to make a directory for your project
- `cd` to your project folder/dir
- type `code .` to open up vs code in this directory
- Now you can use the **integrated vs code terminal**, please select the **terminal**, not the **powershell**
- type `pip3 freeze`, it will show up all the installed **packages and dependencies** on global scope/system
- but we gonna have a **venv** where we will install our necessary packages and dependencies
- type `python3 -m venv ./venv` to create venv inside your current project folder, please ensure you are inside the folder before running this command
  [if you are not using python 3, then the command will be `python -m venv ./venv`]
- to actiavte environment,
  on mac, run `source ./venv/bin/activate`
  on windows, run `.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat` [if it doesn't work, try to put your absolute path]
- you can check what is installed inside venv using `pip freeze`, you will see nothing inside the venv
- Now you can install django inside venv for your project
- inside vs code, press **shift+cmd+p** and search for **Python: select interpreter** and choose **venv** [enter interpreter path>find>project folder>venv>Scripts>python.exe]
- then you can notice the **settings.json** file inside **.vscode folder** in your project
- to deactivate the environment, just type `deactivate`

Still, if you don't see the **.vscode** folder inside your project folder, you can create it manually.

- Create a folder and name it **.vscode**
- inside the folder, create **setting.json** file and paste the following code

  {
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
  "./YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME",
  ]
  }

for instance, system search for custom modules here in this extraPath if the module is not available in your system or user environment path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-project-environment-for-the-django-tutorial) on the VSCode official docs.

You don't need to create the `settings.json` file, it was created by the VSCode, you can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for the details.

And the interpreter-related information you can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).